# Identifier restriction in global scope

Tags: c++

> In addition, identifiers defined outside a function may not begin with an underscore.

Why does this restriction apply only to variables outside of a function? Not sure what purpose this could serve.

Comment: Because ones declared in a function would shadow those. It shouldn't just be out of functions, though. You can still do it with class members etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Short answer: in order to avoid name collision with the standard libraries (e.g. STL, libc, etc.)